# Dir function error "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Tags: vb6

I have made a control panel within vb6, and in one of the forms, I want the user of the program to change the name of the existing text file or rewrite it. I am using the `Dir` function as shown below:

```
If Check3.Value = 1 Then
 If Dir(File.Path + " \ " + Form2.filetext.Text, vbNormal) <> 0 Then
  intfile = MsgBox("File existing. Do you want to delete the existing file?", vbYesNo, "WARNING")
  If intfile = 6 Then
   Open File.Path + "\" + Form2.filetext.Text For Output As #3
  Else
   Open File.Path + "\" + Form2.filetext.Text For Append As #3
  End If
 Else
  Open File.Path + "\" + Form2.filetext.Text For Output As #3
 End If
Else
 Close #3
End If
End Sub
```

But when I chose my file or changing the name, the Dir function gives me this error

> wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

I would appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: Several issues I see on the Dir line:  use "&" for concatenation, remove the spaces around " \ ", and the Dir function returns a string not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Change Line

If Dir(File.Path + " \ " + Form2.filetext.Text, vbNormal) <> 0 Then

to

If Dir(File.Path + "\" + Form2.filetext.Text, vbNormal) <> "" Then

Add "Option Explicit" without Quotes on top of code of form and check for undeclared variable

Comment: Can you use `+` for concat instead of `&` ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I changed it as you suggested but unfortuntlety  I have the same error....

Comment: @StayOnTarget Yes we can use both + or & for concat in vb6

Comment: @AlirezaZahedi Exactly on which line you are getting the Error  I Assume File Variable in your code is file control check this also